# Forking a child and calling gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork

I'm trying to make a program which is getting a directory path, opening the directory and then compiling the c file inside.

```
    //open current directory
    currDir=opendir(fullpath);
    //get the c file, ignore hidden files
    while((cfile=readdir(currDir))!=NULL)
    {
        if(cfile->d_name[0]!='.')
            break;
    }
    /*compile c file*/

    //child process
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        fullpath=realloc(fullpath, sizeof(char)*(strlen(fullpath)+strlen(cfile->d_name)+1));
        strcat(fullpath,cfile->d_name);
        execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "/usr/bin/gcc", "-o", "comp.out", fullpath,NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
```

As you see, in the child process I'm creating the full path of the c file (otherwise it won't find it), and then calling gcc, but I get the following error:

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
```

1. Any ideas what's wrong? Why won't it compile the files successfuly? Please note that I do succeed in compiling them manually through the terminal.
2. Another question that I haven't found an answer to is, how to force the comp.out file to be created in the directory of the c file? Because if I call gcc with a full path of the file, the .out file will be created in the home directory.

I tried to google and research before but couldn't find an answer to both questions.
Thanks for help.

Comment: For #2: specify the full path as you do for the input. For #1, probably an environment issue (`PATH`).

Comment: regarding #2: what do you mean? can you give an example?
regarding #1: and what can I do about it?

Comment: What don't you understand about #2? What are you doing to the path for the source file? Why don't you just do the same thing for the output?

Comment: You have a possible memory leak in that you don't `free` the memory allocated for `fullpath`. It will be free'd when the child process exits, but it's something that most code-reviews would look hard upon. In fact, as we don't know how you declare `fullpath` you might even try to reallocate an array for all we know. **And** if the path in `fullpath` doesn't end with a slash your path will be all wrong.

Comment: fullpath when I open the directory: /home/aviad/workspace/test/dean/ex11.c. And I dont understand how to write the gcc command (regarding question 2). should it be like this?: gcc -o comp.out [filepath] [filedestination]? or reversed? I tried both and didn't work.

Comment: This code runs without an error here as it should. Run `strace -f yourprogram` and look for any lines mentioning `ld` in the output. If something like `stat64("/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld", ...)` fails, you may have a broken installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
execlp()
```

instead. It searches in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: well, problem solved, needed to add the PATH manually in the eclipse configurations.